# Is it possible to localize datatable cell editor control buttons in YUI2?

Tags: alfresco-share, yui-datatable, yui2

I'm wondering if it is possible to localize the labels on the textbox cell editor of the YUI2 datatable:
[image]

In the image above, I'd like to be able to change the label on the save and cancel buttons. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See LABEL_CANCEL and LABEL_SAVE in [BaseCellEditor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.BaseCellEditor.html#property_LABEL_CANCEL)